# Export matlab data to MS Access

Tags: database, matlab, ms-access

Given some matlab data, e.g. a table or array, how do I write the result as an MS Access file. Ideally, as one individual table?

My idea is to export individual tables of big data and then to call the Database and query custom outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Matlab [Database Toolbox](https://it.mathworks.com/products/database.html).
It takes a little effort configuring it, but it lets you connect to every type of database:

> The toolbox can connect to standard ODBC-compliant and JDBC-compliant databases, including Oracle®, SAS®, MySQL®, Sybase®, Microsoft® SQL Server®, Microsoft® Access™, and PostgreSQL®

You will find help to start using it [here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/database/data-export-from-matlab.html).

Comment: Do you have a concrete example of how to query the storage of the data?

Comment: The concrete code to export data is to use: `datainsert(conn,tablename,colnames,data)`. The harder part is, as written, to configure connection. However, you can find better explanation of what parameters use [here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/datainsert.html) and [here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/database/data-export-from-matlab.html)

Comment: Why do you need a connection when you just have a MS Access database locally?

Comment: Because Matlab doesn't simply "see" Ms Access. You have to use a odbc or jdbc connections